# Where to build a Hybrid App?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I want to ceate a Hybrid App with html5,cc3,JS,Jquery mobile,SQL,AJAX
and it's my first attempt.
What platform do you suggest to begin with the building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for Phonegap / Cordova, it is open source through which you can create application in Adnroid, iOS, Windows & Blackberry.

You can check [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) for more info.

Also you can download [Sample Phonegap Application](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fphonegap%2Fphonegap-start&ei=Nb7mVNzYFJaXuAT6q4H4BQ&usg=AFQjCNFWb4Vis4m77sf3sRh3jI2Dsw8T6w&sig2=j--1g3kkskC-bd3VReMK_g&bvm=bv.86475890,d.c2E) to get started.

Besides you can learn Phonegap set up [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap-from-scratch-introduction--mobile-9171)

Besides phonegap you can go for

1. Appcelerator  Titanium:
2. Sencha Touch

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i will check it out and I hope you are right  and not searching around for the proper one :)

Comment: I have been using Phonegap since past 2 years :)

Answer (score 1):

Use cordova for building hybrid application, for documentation go here
      http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use Intel xdk to build and create hybrid application.Its a useful for building android,ios and windows application